# Add the = key to intellisense complete in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

Anyone know how to add the = key(or any other character) to the Member List Commit Characters for visual studio 2019 Intellisense using C#.

For C/C++ it's done like this, incase someone stumbled here looking for this

```
Tools-> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced-> Intellisense -> Member List Commit Characters -> [text box of characters]
```

Comment: I'm noting that `=` already works for me in VS2019 C#. I don't suppose you've changed the intellisense completion mode? You can switch it by going to Edit > IntelliSense > Switch between automatic [...]

Comment: I did not switch from auto to tab, although I didn't know that option was there so thanks for that.  I am in Auto mode.  Brackets, space, enter  they all work to commit the intellisense suggestion.  just not =

Comment: When you type something like `priv` and the intellisense menu suggests `private`, then you press `=`, what happens? Also, which version of VS2019 are you using?

Comment: Version is Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.10.0
When I type priv and press = I am left with "priv ="  but if I type priv (  I will get "private ("... **Edit**   ok... I just restarted Visual Studio and tested this.... it works!!!  I can't explain it.  cycling the power coupling resolves all problems it seems.  Thanks for you time, I will likely delete this question soon as it serves no purpose.